# Parse a string as a map in SASS

Tags: css, arrays, string, parsing, sass

I have a few variables in SASS:

```
$tablet: 'max-width 48em';
$desktop: 'max-width 62em';
```

I want the variables to be treated as a single entity as I'm iterating on them. However they then need to be passed into another mixin as a map.

```
@mixin rwd( $classes: (), $breakpoints: () ) {
  @content;
  @for $i from 1 through length($classes) {
    $breakpoint: unquote( nth($breakpoints, $i) );
    &---#{nth($classes, $i)} {
      @include media( $breakpoint ) {
        @content;
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Called with `@include rwd( upto-desktop, $upto-desktop ) { }`

The issue is that when I use [unquote](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unquote-instance_method) in SASS, the result is not treated as a map.

Is there a SASS function I can call to parse the result as a map?
Or any alternatives?

Comment: The unquote is *only* for unquoting strings, the result is still a string.  I am not sure why you  thought you were going to get anything different.

Comment: why don't you just use a map to beginn with?

Comment: The `media` mixin requires a map, but because I'm iterating before that it treats each substring as part of a map. So I end up with `min-width: max-width`.

Comment: Ok so specifying as a map to start seems to work: wrapping in `(` `)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not directly an answer to the asked question, I have found a better way of achieving the desired effect.

By creating a map of breakpoints and their associated values as a global variable, I simplified the `rwd` mixin by comparing a parameter to a map key. If it exists then use that key's value in the `media` mixin:

```
$breakpoints: (
  mobile: max-width 47.9375em,
  tablet: 48em,
  hd: 62em
);

@mixin rwd( $names: () ) {
  @content;

  @each $name in $names {
    @each $bp in $breakpoints {
      @if nth($bp,1) == $name {
        &---MQ#{nth($bp, 1)} {
          @include media( nth($bp, 2) ) {
            @content;
          }
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}

.black {
  @include rwd( mobile tablet hd ) {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
}
```

This will generate the following CSS:

```
.black {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 47.9375em) {
  .black---MQmobile {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .black---MQtablet {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 62em) {
  .black---MQhd {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
}
```

The only caveat to this approach is that now I can't simply use the `$mobile` variable in the `media` mixin, I have to use a `map-get`

There are two possible approaches:

Create a helper function that gets the parameter from the specific map (and you can give it a really short name for convenience).

```
@function bp( $bp ) {
  @return map-get( $breakpoints, $bp );
}

.blue {
  @include media ( bp(mobile) ) {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

Create a variable and assign it to the `map-get` function

```
$mobile: map-get( $breakpoints, mobile );

.red {
  @include media ( $mobile ) {
    background: red;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

Edit this on Codepen: http://codepen.io/craigmdennis/pen/Qydewy?editors=010

Comment: You probably want to add some error checking in the bp function and [warn the user](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_6) if the key isn't in the map.